# WAP that utilises existing WiFi security

Tags: wireless-networking

I believe I need a WAP to provide WiFi into a dead zone, is there such a device that receives incoming signal via ethernet, produces the WiFi signal that uses the same WiFi network and security from which it receives? As I am trying to avoid needing to use a seperate WiFi network.

Comment: Yes, you can have a wifi repeater or you can extend the wifi range by adding another router in "Bridge Mode". https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/how-to-use-a-spare-router-as-a-wifi-extender/ You can connect both Wireless Access points via a cable. Or you can use the wireless connection.

Comment: You probably mean a WiFi Access Point? (WAP as an acronym can and often is confused with the decades old "Wireless Application Protocol": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol). Now, as stated above you surely can but you'll have to learn some details about it to avoid the confusion you have now. Namely, Ethernet and WiFi are different technologies that may or may not be used in the same network. If the you're asking about something *that receives incoming signal via ethernet* it cannot be using *same WiFi network and security from which it receives* (...)

Comment: (...) simply because **it isn't "receiving" anything from WiFi, it's connected by Ethernet**. Both suggestions in the first comment assume WiFi to WiFi. Using Ethernet as you want is also possible and in many cases preferable but it necessarily creates a new AP (access point) albeit in the same network.

Comment: Finally, please understand hardware recommendations are off-topic here so don't ask.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe I need a WAP to provide WiFi into a dead zone, is there such a device that receives incoming signal via ethernet, produces the WiFi signal that uses the same WiFi network and security from which it receives? As I am trying to avoid needing to use a seperate WiFi network.

That's literally just a WAP.

A wireless access point *always* generates its own Wi-Fi signal. It does not make sense for such a device to "use the same WiFi network and security from which it receives" because it *doesn't* receive any Wi-Fi network – that kind of thing doesn't go over Ethernet. An Ethernet cable doesn't carry Wi-Fi signals, it carries just the IP packets.¹

But a "plain" access point (i.e. not a router, or at least not operating in "router" mode) will always let you access the same IP network that it receives via Ethernet. That's enough to avoid the need for "creating a separate Wi-Fi network" – you can configure the AP to use the *same network name* (and the same security settings) and you will have a single Wi-Fi network, with a single entry in the network list, that has two 'points of access' which devices automatically switch between.

Again, the important part for having this work is to make sure the device does not create a new *IP* network. (For example, if you want to repurpose a wireless router as a WAP, you have to reconfigure it as a "bridge".) The Wi-Fi part is basically automatic as soon as you set an identical name.

---

But because of the first point (each AP generates its own Wi-Fi signal), keep in mind that different APs will support different Wi-Fi features, and therefore might not be treated identically by devices – e.g. given a network that consists of multiple APs, certain client devices might strongly prefer a distant 5 GHz-capable AP over a nearby 2.4 GHz-only one – so make sure overlapping APs have similar capabilities, even if it means reconfiguring a second router to act as an AP.

---

<sup>¹ In other words, it is not a "Wi-Fi cable" as some people call it. (Though actual "Wi-Fi cables" do exist, but they're *coax* cables going from a special WAP *to* a separate antenna, often on the roof pointed at a different building.)</sup>

Comment: Brilliant! +1 If I thought this was an answer I would have posted pretty much the same as you did instead of the comment(s) I wrote at the same time as you :)